# JPA @JoinTable - Three ID Columns

Tags: java, hibernate, unique-constraint, multiple-columns, join

I have a situation that is quite similar to the one outlined in this question's diagram: [JPA. JoinTable and two JoinColumns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572072/jpa-jointable-and-two-joincolumns), although with different issues.

I have three tables: `Function`, `Group`, and `Location`. Currently, I have a join table set up between `Location` and `Group` using `@JoinTable`. It is `@ManyToMany` on both sides, and works perfectly fine.

I am attempting to add the constraint that no `Location` should be associated with more than one `Group` that has the same `Function`. So I added a column for `Function` to my join table in my SQL schema and a uniqueness constraint across the `Location` and `Function` columns, like so:

```
create table function_table (
  id varchar(50),
  primary key(id)
);

create table group_table (
  id varchar(50),
  function_id varchar(50) not null,
  primary key(id)
);

alter table group_table add constraint FK_TO_FUNCTION foreign key (function_id) references function_table;

create table location_table (
  id varchar(50),
  primary key(id)
);

create table group_location_join (
  location_id varchar(50) not null,
  group_id varchar(50) not null,
  function_id varchar(50) not null,
  primary key(location_id, group_id, function_id),
  unique(location_id, function_id)
);

alter table group_location_join add constraint FK_TO_LOCATION foreign key (location_id) references location_table;
alter table group_location_join add constraint FK_TO_GROUP foreign key (group_id) references group_table;
alter table group_location_join add constraint FK_TO_FUNCTION foreign key (function_id) references function_table;
```

I then attempted to set up the following in my model entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "function_table")
public class Function {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", length = 50)
  private String id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "group_table")
public class Group {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", length = 50)
  private String id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "function_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
  private Function function;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "group_location_join",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
                   @JoinColumn(name = "function_id", referencedColumnName = "function_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="location_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
  private Set<Location> locations;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "location_table")
public class Location {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", length = 50)
  private String id;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "group_location_join",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="location_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
                   @JoinColumn(name = "function_id", referencedColumnName = "function_id")})
  private Set<Group> groups;
}
```

(Obviously, there is more to these entities, but I stripped them down to only the parts relevant to this question.)

This does not work. When I write a simple test to create a `Location` associated with a `Group` that is associated with a `Function`, the minute I try to flush the session to commit the transaction, Hibernate gives me this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: my.package.Group cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable
```

I think what's happening is that Hibernate is getting confused, throwing up its hands, and saying "I'll just serialize it, send it to the database, and hope it knows what's going on."

When I add `implements Serializable` and add a `serialVersionUID` to `Group`, I then get this:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: user lacks privilege or object not found: FUNCTION_ID
```

I'm not really sure how to proceed at this point, or if perhaps I have already proceeded too far down the wrong path. Maybe I'm not thinking about the SQL correctly, and there is a much easier way to ensure this constraint that doesn't involve all this ridiculousness.

**Edit:** In my system, the DAOs for the tables involved have no save capabilities. Which means that as long as my constraint is set up in the database, my application doesn't care; it can't insert things that violate the constraint because it can't insert things at all.

**Edit 2:** I never originally solved the stated problem, and instead simply added a third column in my database schema without touching the Java code, as stated in my first **Edit** section above. But I have since experimented with creating an explicit join table object with an `@Embedded` compound key, and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a composite primary key. In Hibernate you can do it using the `@Embeddable` annotation. In the example below you can find the way to use a composite key for two entities.

I believe you can move forward with this example and create your own version of primary key.

[Mapping ManyToMany with composite Primary key and Annotation:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405746/mapping-manytomany-with-composite-primary-key-and-annotation)

Comment: Do you mean a composite key in `Group`? Because I do not in any way want that. When anything else in the system references `Group` by primary key, it should only be dealing with the `id` column. If I give `Group` a composite primary key, this will change that fact; everything will be looking up `Group`s by `id` AND `function_id`. I do not want this. I only want to get `function_id` into the `group_location_join` table.