# JPA wrong number of columns

Tags: jpa, join, hibernate-mapping, composite-primary-key

Using `Spring Framework JPA` I have an `Entity`

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ComposityKey.class)
@Table(name="table1")
public class Table1 {
    @Id
    @Column(name="tableId)
    private int tableId;

    @Id
    private int tableId2;
    ...
}
```

2nd `Entity` contains a reference to `Table1`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table2")
public class Table2 {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="tableId")
    private Table1 table1;
}
```

Now I'm getting the obvious `AnnotationException`

```
A Foreign key refering Table1 from Table2 has the wrong number of column. should be 2
```

`Table2` doesn't have `tableId2` as a value

So how can i `JoinColumn` on a *Composite Key*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA @JoinTable - Three ID Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899736/jpa-jointable-three-id-columns)

Comment: Not sure It's duplicate, Not same Exception. Also notice that i am missing one of the id's in the second column - How will I be able to use EmbededId without the data?